# WMI - Win 2k8 - How do I tell what it's dependancies are?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, process, windows-service, wmi

I've got a server that'll boot and log let you term serv into it at 6 min but acutally become useful at 18 min from hitting reboot.  After rooting around in the logs I strongly think it's a service timing out and my current suspect is the WMI service.  This used to be a hyper-v host but has been repurpsed w/o formatting to a Server 2k7 R2 OCS director.  I normally would be more through but we are on a tight timeline with consultants. :(

To the meat of the matter: How do I tell what services the WMI service uses as dependants?  I can see what depends on it and I'd rather not have to look through EVERY process to determine this.

Beyond this, if anyone's had any ideas/suggestions on how to troubleshoot WMI or this kind of error or tools would be welcome.  I want to re-install WMI but I don't think that's reasonable/plasuable without doing a 'repair' install of the server.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

The service properties window you viewed from the Services snap-in should have 2 sections in the Dependencies tab.  The first one is for *services it depends on*.  The other is for *services that depend on it*.  I would've thought you'd seen that already unless I'm missing something in your question.

As for troubleshooting, I was going to recommend the Diagnostics-Performance event log to start with.  But for the life of me, I can't find it on my Server 2008 install, only on my Vista install.  Event logs in general will be your friend though.  Take a look through the various logs in *Applications and Services Logs*.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess I missed it because it was directly in front of me.  I'll go through and see if the daignostic montering will yeild anything helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Process Monitor from SysInternals (now Microsoft since they were acquired a few years back) will allow you to do boot time logging of all or a filtered set of processes. This will generate a large amount of data but it will allow you to drill down into every dependency and see what is actually happening.

If WMI is actually causing this my suspicion is that a boot\startup task is being triggered that is causing WMI to execute a query or set of queries that are attempting to go into far too much detail or are timing out because of the fact that you have re-purposed rather than re-built the server.

The Task Scheduler in Administrative Tools in the Control Panel can be used to find such scheduled items but I find the interface clumsy. The command line tools Schtasks will give you all of the details for scheduled system\user tasks that are scheduled to run at startup, user logon time or periodically and you can pipe the output to a file for easy searching.

From a cmd window:
schtasks /query /v /FO List > tasks.tmp
Now open tasks.tmp in an editor and search for entries that have a Startup Type of "At system start up" or "At logon time".

Schtasks will also let you disable specific tasks if you find entries that you want to remove, just remember that some tasks may be automatically restored by system policies.

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't know about that tool.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\DisabledComponents - Dword value.  I took it from **FFFFFFFF** to **FF** and poof!  Login time is now under 3:23 min.

Why does it care about the last 26 bits you ask?  I have not a clue - I'm just trying to accept it.  :)

Comment: Can you post what led you to that?